# Converting upTime Function from Javascript to Jquery and use single functions for multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in Javascript, that counts up from a specific date-time. I intend to use one function for multiple IDs so I'm trying to convert to jQuery but can't seem to get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function upTime(countTo, yearField, daysField, hoursField, minutesField, secondsField) {
        now = new Date();
        countTo = new Date(countTo);
        difference = (now-countTo);

        days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
        years = Math.floor(days / 365);
        if (years > 1){ days = days - (years * 365)}
        hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
        mins=Math.floor(((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
        secs=Math.floor((((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);

        document.getElementById(yearField).firstChild.nodeValue = years;
        document.getElementById(daysField).firstChild.nodeValue = days;
        document.getElementById(hoursField).firstChild.nodeValue = hours;
        document.getElementById(minutesField).firstChild.nodeValue = mins;
        document.getElementById(secondsField).firstChild.nodeValue = secs;

      upTime.to=setTimeout(function(){ upTime(countTo, yearField, daysField, hoursField, minutesField, secondsField); },1000);
    }


     window.onload=function() {
    upTime('2010-12-03 23:12:00', 'y1', 'd1', 'h1', 'm1', 's1'); // ****** Change this line!
            // Month,Day,Year,Hour,Minute,Second
        }; 
</script>
```

Based on Eric's comment. I've come up with this jQuery plugin below. Is there anything I'm missing or not doing right?

```
      jQuery.fn.extend({
    upTime: function() {  

    return this.each(function() {
        var  countTo = $(this).attr('val');
      var  yearField = $(this).find(".y1");
      var  daysField = $(this).find(".d1");
      var  hoursField =  $(this).find(".h1");
      var minutesField =  $(this).find(".m1");
     var   secondsField =  $(this).find(".m1");

        now = new Date();
        countTo = new Date(countTo);
        difference = (now-countTo);

        days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
        years = Math.floor(days / 365);
        if (years > 1){ days = days - (years * 365)}
        hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
        mins=Math.floor(((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
        secs=Math.floor((((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);

        $(yearField).prepend(years);
        $(daysField).prepend(days);
         $(hoursField).prepend(hours);
         $(minutesField).prepend(mins);
         $(secondsField).prepend(secs);
    });
 }
});


// Use the newly created  method
$(".counter").upTime();
```

Need it to work with loops such as these below:

```
<!-- Multiple loops ->
<ul class="counter" val="2017-12-10 16:11:00">
    <li class="y1" >00<br>YR(S)</li>
    <li class="d1" >00<br>DY(S)</li>
    <li class="h1" >00<br>HR(S)</li>
    <li class="m1" >00<br>MI(S)</li>
    <li class="s1" >00<br>SE(S)</li>
</ul> 

<ul class="counter" val="2018-01-10 16:11:00">
    <li class="y1">00<br>YR(S)</li>
    <li class="d1">00<br>DY(S)</li>
    <li class="h1">00<br>HR(S)</li>
    <li class="m1">00<br>MI(S)</li>
    <li class="s1">00<br>SE(S)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Getting it to work with "multiple ids" has very little to do with "converting it to jQuery".  You should work first on that, before deciding that it must be jQuery.  What exact issue are you having?

Comment: @Taplar I'm trying to iterate  through all "ul .counter" instances, get the date value and do a countup timer for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

```
// Plugin definition.
jQuery.fn.extend({
    upTime: function() {  

    return this.each(function() {
        var  countTo = $(this).attr('val');
      var  yearField = $(this).find(".y1");
      var  daysField = $(this).find(".d1");
      var  hoursField =  $(this).find(".h1");
      var minutesField =  $(this).find(".m1");
     var   secondsField =  $(this).find(".s1");

        now = new Date();
        countTo = new Date(countTo);
        difference = (now-countTo);

        days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
        years = Math.floor(days / 365);
        if (years > 1){ days = days - (years * 365)}
        hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
        mins=Math.floor(((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
        secs=Math.floor((((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);

        $(yearField).html(years+"<br><span>Year</span>");
        $(daysField).html(days+"<br><span>Day</span>");
         $(hoursField).html(hours+"<br><span>Hour</span>");
         $(minutesField).html(mins+"<br><span>Mins</span>");
         $(secondsField).html(secs+"<br><span>Secs</span>");

    });
 }
});


         setInterval(function(){
    $(".counter").upTime();
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to jQuery.fn.extend() function, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  upTime: function(options) {
    ... Do the things you need to initialize the counter
  }
});
```

Then you can do

```
$(".counter").upTime({
        countTo: $(this).find(".c1").attr('val'),
        yearField: $(this).find(".y1").attr('val'),
        daysField: $(this).find(".d1").attr('val'),
        hoursField: $(this).find(".h1").attr('val'),
        minutesField: $(this).find(".m1").attr('val'),
        secondsField: $(this).find(".m1").attr('val')
    });
```

Only a thing, remember that the this object references the context in wich is the code, not the element itself.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  It points out the issue with the `this` context reference, but does not fix it.  It also mentions the extend method, but not the implementation, which is a comment.

Comment: Really? I think it would be easy from this... OK, you want me to answer or to implement a plugin entirely ?...

Comment: I'm simply saying the answer is incomplete.  If you don't want to provide a complete answer, this would be more appropriate as comments to the question, pointing the OP in the direction they should go.